# How to make a device visible to the internet?

Tags: networking, ssh, port-forwarding, raspberry-pi, hosts

[moved here from Network Engineering SE]

I realize this is a simple question that is likely answered on various SE forms but I can't seem to ask it in a way that gives me the information I need, so thank you for your patience.

I'm trying to expose my raspberry pi to the internet so that I can ssh into it from somewhere other than my local network. I can currently ssh in using the IPv4 address.

What am I missing here? Something to do with port forwarding? I can't tell what general steps I need to go through to get this working so a high level response would be perfect.

Comment: I would suggest you to configure port forwarding on your router (external interface) to the SSH server, please refer to:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18939285/how-to-access-my-ssh-linux-server-from-outside-my-home-network/18939422